# When using dependency injection, where do all the new operators go?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, dependency-injection, tdd

I've been reading about dependency injection, and I understand the basic concept that a method should receive what it needs from its caller rather than creating such items itself. As a result, `new` operators get removed from the method almost entirely (certain basic objects would be exempt, of course - one example of this I found was for things like `StringBuilder`s which seem like they'd be insane to have to pass in).

My question sounds deceptively simple, but I suspect the answer is actually fairly complex: Where do all of the `new` operators go?

The answer seems straightforward at first: the `new` operator just gets pushed to the method which calls the method that needs the object. The problem with this, however, is that the calling method is likely also under test and so that `new` gets pushed up from calling method to calling method until eventually you get to a root method (which at this point seems crazy untestable) that creates an obscene amount of objects to get used at various points down the call stack. The situation becomes even more complicated when you consider that that root method is the root of a large variety of other methods, and so would need to create objects for every possibility. This also creates a performance problem since you would quickly be left with a large number of objects which are never actually used, but which must be instantiated anyway "just in case".

It is quite obvious to me that I have missed some vital piece of knowledge which is so apparent to other developers that nobody thinks to describe it in a blog post. However, I obviously cannot know what I do not know, so I humbly ask that I be let in on the secret: Where do all the `new` operators go?

I should mention that I'm developing with PHP, so every request starts at the same point, and it seems like that root "method" in `index.php` would need to cover everything the application *could* do, in order to ensure it provides an object for everything it *will* do in the current request. Again, there's a fundamental misunderstanding here, and I'd really love to correct it.

Comment: See if this helps: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/10/where-have-all-the-new-operators-gone/

Answer (score 5):

You've pretty much got it right: they all end up in your **composition root**. See [this interview with Mark Seeman](http://www.infoq.com/articles/DI-Mark-Seemann), nearer to the bottom, for an explanation of why this is a good practice and is important.

Also of note: dependency injection is meant for services, not entities or value objects. So e.g. injecting `IUserRepository` makes sense, but `IUser` not so much---and certainly not `StringBuilder`s. That might help clarify things, in light of your parenthetical about more primitive types: the division is not really how primitive they are, but rather what their role is in the system.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite obvious - the `new` operator went to the DI container, when all instantiating happens.

There also shouldn't be any performance problems, because services are instantiated on demand - when you ask for them for the first time.

For development in PHP I suggest you to look into [Symfony Framework](http://symfony.com/) which implements DI very well and it's an example of flawless and pure architecture.

Comment: I should have clarified that I'm largely talking about constructor injection here. Admittedly I don't know much about DI containers, as they just seemed ugly to me - essentially a massive "global" variable/singleton which works like magic with a method just assuming the container's in the right state to work, rather than being passed dependencies directly. You also say that this container needs to be coded be able to create any instantiation chain necessary, which still sounds a lot like my "root method" described in the question. (Sorry if I sound naive with this; it's only because I am.)

Comment: Regarding your edit with regard to Symphony - I didn't think it necessary to add here, but I'm also trying to roll my own toy "framework" here in addition to the small app that will sit on top of it. My goal here is to learn a) how frameworks work, and b) how DI is properly applied. An answer of "just use this, it already does everything for you" doesn't help, since I won't learn anything. I'm very much a junior developer still, and I'm trying to rectify that by getting my hands dirty. I'm just having issues understanding certain aspects of the concepts as well as I would like to.

Comment: I suggest you to read this series of articles from Miško Hevery: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/ He describes what DI is for and how you should apply it correctly.

Comment: DI containers are not magic, they just construct the objects for you based on configuration or autowiring.

Comment: @ondrej: don't automatically think that DI is related to DI **Container**. I usually use the DI concept, but I don't really like the "put all your services in a big array like classe" use that begins to spread.

Comment: OK, replace DI container with Assembler object in my comments. I know that DI is a general principle, but DI container makes a lot of your work easier.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection is usually used in MVC apps. In those case, the "`new`", as you call it, usually go into the Controler layer.

When calling the Model, the Controler instanciate dependencies, and give them to the Model, and then calls the business methodes exposed by the Model.

But don't think DI is about "removing the `new`s". It is about decoupling. The less classes instanciate (and thus "know") other classes, the less is can be harmed by changed in these other classeS.

Another aim is to make testing easier. If you have a method that needs to compose and send mail, it's hard to test if a mail is correctly composed. However, if you remove the dependency of actually sending the mail, from this class to another class, and only give an object that can send mail to this method, when you'll write your test, instead of giving this method an object that can really send mail, you'll give this method an object that only **fake sending mail**. Do you see the point ?

Comment: Let's assume I'm building my own toy framework as a learning experience. Should I consider "BeginRequest -> Controller" as it's own testing unit, and "Controller -> LeafMethods" as a separate unit, and use that as a demarcation point for different unit test batches?

Comment: I understand the testing/coupling aspect (my interest in trying TDD is what led me here to begin with). I also didn't say DI was about *removing* `new` operators, only that it required that they be moved up the chain. Your mail sending object needs a thing to send mail, and you decouple that from the thing that does the mailing by passing the object a mailer. My point was simply that the mailer had to come from somewhere above that object, and I'm just trying to figure out where. Sorry if this is coming off horribly noobish/naive; I'm just trying to learn. :)

Answer (score -2):

DI is frequently used in tandem with IOC Containers (once the scale of the app exceeds a certain threshold). Containers are configured such that they can service requests for a particular type/interface and return completely constructed objects (with required dependencies).

So instead of doing a `new ConcreteType()`, you ask the container `container.Get<Interface/Type>()`.

That said, since I read the comments indicating you're just starting out, I'd recommend not rolling your own DI Framework (it's a common time-sink). Use and study the code for existing functional DI libraries like MEF/Unity/any other.

Comment: Er, careful, you seem to be implying one should use the DI container as a service locator, i.e. replace all `new`s with `container.Get`s. Might want to edit that?

Comment: @Domenic - I fail to see the mistake. If I was using a DI container, I'd be using it to create all public Roles (except maybe internal class dependencies that would not ever change for a specific object).

Comment: @Gishu I think the point Domenic was trying to make is that if you're using the container in that fashion, you're doing Service Location, not Dependency Injection. That's commonly thought of as a misuse of an IoC container, because it misses the point of inversion of control.

Comment: @Gishu yes, @Eric King has it right. For more information see http://www.infoq.com/articles/DI-Mark-Seemann

Comment: @Eric @Domenic The top-level objects still need to be "called out" service-locator in the 'composition root'. The dependencies are then filled in by the DI container. Inspite of this there might be times, when you want to locate types dynamically and plug them in (Mef style), in which case too you'd need a Service locator style call. So my approach is based on 'Service Locator when absolutely required and depend on Container to inject all dependencies'

Comment: @Gishu That's fine, as long as we remember the distinction between Service Location and Dependency Injection, which are two different patterns used two different ways to accomplish two different purposes. What you described in your answer is using a container to perform Service Location, which is not what the question was asking about, hence the comments.