# Does the prototype pattern comply with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, prototype-pattern

During my learning about dependency injection (and acquiring first practical experience) I was wondering about one problem that occurred to me thinking about one concrete project that I'd like to tackle with DI in the near future.

For different analyses I'd like to create objects of an injected dependency dynamically, for I'd need an arbitrary number of them, which may vary due to users interactions with my program. I thought about implementing this requirement as an abstract prototype pattern

```
public interface IAnalysis
{
    SomeDataType DoSomething();
    IAnalysis CreateObject();
}
```

Classes derived from IAnalysis will be responsible for returning a new object of that class from `CreateObject()`. Dependent classes can create new objects without knowing the concrete type, but only rely on the interface, hence a major concept of DI is complied to. Anyway, classes derived from IAnalysis will have to create new objects with the `new` keyword. I read that creating objects with `new` should be avoided outside the injector when using DI, thus I am not quite sure if this is "allowed" in DI. On the other hand this seems like a quite sensible solution to me, for the classes only create new objects of themselves, which actually should not hurt the DI principle.

Is the concept I thought of sensible? Are there any other solutions I can use to achieve this? I actually thought about abstract factories, but this would hurt the DI principle to my understanding.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you might be confusing DI and IoC.  They are related but certainly not the same thing.  DI requires that an object's dependencies be passed in from the outside rather than created on the inside.  There's nothing in that that precludes you from creating a dependency via its type's constructor.

Comment: No, I actually meant DI. I am planning to have an injector class which builds up my dependency graph. Does this make a real difference?

Comment: Re: _"I read that constructors should be avoided when using DI"_. No; it's not the constructors themselves that should be avoided, but invoking them directly via the `new` operator. Constructors are known to be very useful in DI (namely for injecting required dependencies).

Comment: @stakx I maybe should've written "[...] should be avoided outside the injector". Of course they are needed, particularly to inject the dependencies.

Comment: @PaulKertscher: That would still be inaccurate. I wanted to point out that constructors and `new …` expressions are not the same thing. (The latter create new objects *using* the former; but `new …` expressions *aren't* constructors.) The advice you read was most likely about `new` (because only then does it make sense), yet you cite it as, "I read that *constructors* should …".

Comment: @stakx Now I got your point. Of course they are not the same, but does this stringent differentiation make sense if there is no way to call a constructor w/o `new`? This would imply that calling constructors outside the injector should be avoided if creating objects with `new` should be avoided outside the injector. Or is there any possibility calling a constructor w/o new?

Comment: Yes. Here's the alternative that matters most in DI: Instead of creating a dependency yourself by using `new`, you let another party create the object for you – voilà, you no longer use `new` yourself! (Of course that other party *might* use `new`, but your code doesn't need to know, nor care; what's important is having the dependency available. That "someone else created it" trail will lead you back to the composition root.) This idea is at the core of the IoC aspect of DI: You don't `new` up dependencies whenever and wherever you need them – instead, you receive them / have them injected.

Comment: (cont'd:) And it's in that sense that you should avoid `new` (not constructors!): You shouldn't have `new SomeDependency(…)` sprinkled all over your code base, but instead concentrate it in the composition root (and possibly in factories, which are dependencies themselves that would ideally only be `new`-ed up in the composition root). Note also that this advice only applies for `new`-ing types that you would choose to inject (dependencies/components/services). For example, since you wouldn't choose to inject value types (such as `TimeSpan`), `new`-ing up *these* is OK.

Comment: (cont'd:) Related question: [When using dependency injection, where do all the new operators go?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6388442/240733)

Comment: @stakx _"[...]and possibly in factories, which are dependencies themselves that would ideally only be new-ed up in the composition root[...]"_ 

This is now getting closer to my original issue. Let's assume that I have a factory. What does this factory do? Shouldn't this factory `new` the objects created by the factory?

Comment: Again, avoid `new` only for creating *dependencies*. If some type has internal knowledge of how to build an object, then using `new` is OK. Let's look at a `FooFactory`. The whole raison d'être of a factory is that it encapsulates knowledge of how to build an object; it mustn't delegate that knowledge to an external party. If `FooFactory` didn't know how to build `Foo` objects, it would be redundant. So `new Foo(…)` is OK here. But if the ctor of `Foo` accepts further dependencies, your factory may require them also so it can "forward" them.

Comment: (cont'd:) Now to your case, the prototype pattern: Your `CreateObject` method is essentially meant to create a clone of an instance. Whatever type implements that interface should therefore have internal knowledge of how to clone itself; that requirement is derived from the intention of your interface. So again, using `new TypeThatImplementsTheInterface(…)` is OK here.

Comment: Btw. sorry for the many long comments. I should probably convert them to an answer. What do you think, are they in any way useful to you at all?

Comment: No matter, but a pity that I can't vote your comments as the answer to my question :) Yes, your explanations were helpful, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I read that creating objects with `new` should be avoided outside the injector when using DI […].*

This is only partially true. I will show you, step by step, that `new` has its place, and that it might be just fine to use `new` to implement your prototype pattern.

Let's start by stating the obvious: If we need an instance of type `B`, then it has to be created by someone, somewhere. Let's say we have this:

```
class C
{
    void Baz()
    {
        B b = new B(new A(…));
        b.Bar();
    }
}
```

`Baz` requires a `B` in order to do its work. If we want to avoid `new B(…)`, the best we can do is remove it from this particular place in the code base:

```
class C
{
    C(Func<B> newB) // instead of Func<B>, we could also inject a B directly
    {               // (the difference being that we would no longer control
        this.newB = newB;                        // when the B gets created)
    }

    Func<B> newB;

    void Baz()
    {
        var b = newB();
        b.Bar();
    }
}
```

But the `B` being passed to `C`'s constructor still has to be created somewhere. Only now it's somewhere else.

So what have we gained by avoiding the `new`? `C` is no longer required to have internal knowledge of how exactly to create a `B`.

But how would `Func<B> newB` (i.e. a factory method) itself create a `B` without using `new`? It seems we cannot shy away from `new` forever.

To drive this point home, let's proceed to another, very related example that is a little closer to your issue (implementing the prototype pattern in a DI context): Abstract factories, another design pattern. Let's say that we have a `BFactory` whose sole responsibility is to create instances of type `B`:

```
interface BFactory
{
    B CreateB();
}
```

Can we implement this without the use of `new`? Let's try in the same fashion as above:

```
class RedundantBFactory : BFactory
{
    RedundantBFactory(Func<B> newB)
    {
        this.newB = newB;
    }

    Func<B> newB;

    public B CreateB()
    {
        return newB();
    }
}
```

This would be absolutely pointless! The whole raison d'être of a factory is that it encapsulates knowledge about how to create instances of some type. Just because we wanted to avoid using `new` in our factory, we've externalized exactly that knowledge, rendering the factory as a whole completely redundant (because it just forwards its own main responsibility to another party, which has to do the equivalent work)!

We can conclude that it is reasonable and appropriate to use `new` inside abstract factories and factory methods (such as in `BFactory` or even `newB` above), if we don't want them to be completely redundant:

```
class UsefulBFactory : BFactory
{
    public UsefulAFactory(Func<A> newA)
    {
        this.newA = newA;
    }

    Func<A> newA;

    public B CreateB()
    {
        return new B(newA());
    }
}
```

Now to your prototype pattern: The prototype pattern is essentially about object cloning. That is, all types that implement your `IAnalysis` interface must be able to create clones (copies) of an instance. Just as with the abstract factory example above, the sole purpose of your interface is to encapsulate some form of object creation. This is its reason to exist in the first place, so classes that implement this interface *must not* delegate away that responsibility to an external party. Again, it's completely reasonable to use `new` in this case:

```
class W : IAnalysis
{
    W(X x, Y y, …)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        …
    }

    public IAnalysis CreateObject()
    {
        return new W(x, y, …);
    }
}
```

A final remark, just to underline and complete my initial claim that avoiding `new` doesn't make sense in all cases: Take note that DI shouldn't be used for *everything*, anyway.

Usually, you have to make a decision about which types should be handled by the DI container. These so-called dependencies, or components, or services are usually abstracted away as an `interface` or `abstract class BaseClass`, so that you could possibly substitute one implementation for another later on. The only place where you use `new Service(…)` should be in the composition root, or (as shown above) in abstract factories or factory methods (which are themselves dependencies that will get injected to where you need to create objects at a time of your choosing). If you had `new Service(…)` sprinkled liberally all over your code base, it would be difficult to replace one implementation with another.

But it is perfectly OK to use `new` to create primitive values and instances of value types (such as `string`, `TimeSpan`, etc.). These types are usually not instantiated by the DI container.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that constructors should be avoided when using DI, thus I am
>   not quite sure if this is "allowed" in DI.

That's not how it works, but constructors are an implementation detail of the implementation, and since consumers only know about the abstraction, they can't call the constructor.

But those types need to be created by someone. This someone is the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). If you use [pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), you will be calling those constructors. If you use a DI container, the container will invoke the constructor on your behalf.

Keeping this in mind, classes can be created using the `new` keyword, but when it comes to [injection constructors](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), you should keep this creation local to the composition root. The way to do this is to define the `IAnalysis` implementation **inside** the composition root. This way the rest of the application doesn't need to take a dependency on that concrete type and its constructor. If you use a DI library, that implementation can depend on the container and call it to request a new instance.

Comment: I understand that consumers do not know about constructors and hence won't be able to call them, but I am afraid I do not understand how this is related to my question about using the prototype pattern and calling the constructor *from inside* the implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the concept of dependency injection is, when you inject something to another class.
Now, why do you want to use dependency injection, because of OOP concept, and the class needs to use another class (dependency concept).

Now, the injection concept here, means that you should inject something to the class. How do you inject it? By putting it in a parameter.

You have to create the object outside of the interface, then pass the object / class as parameter, to the interface object.

So, instead of you trying to create an object of the service, why don't you pass in your whatever parameter, or object you need processed, and the interface will return the result for you?

Think of it as a service help desk of a private hit man company (interface objects).
This company (interface object) should be private, they cannot give out their hit man list (the implementation classes).

As a customer, how would you make trade with this company (interface objects)?
You would give out your information, to be used by the company.
Then you will see someone you want killed in the newspaper as the result of their work (the return value of interface objects).

Thank you,

Comment: Very amusing example, but not really an appropriate answer to my question. Talking in the terms of your example I would not like to hire one hitman from a fixed pool of hitmen, but I'd like to create hitmen on demand, for I do not know how many hitmen I'd need (doesn't make sense, though).

Comment: mm.. you're rich.. Anyway, you cannot ask the hit man company to submit their hit men list. It is the rule of the game. You can, however, ask another provider company, who does the hit man company creation (which may be a factory class) here?